# NiFi: Too many Open files Unable to start FlowController

Tags: apache-nifi

I started noticing this error and my Nifi won't start at all.

```
org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository/partition-28/19774.journal: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
```

Not sure what caused this.

I removed everything from flow_repository and that seems to have fixed the Issue.

Just trying to figure out the root cause in case this happens in Prod !!

Answer (score 3):

You will likely want to increase the max number of file handles on the operating system.

See the Linux System Configuration section here:

https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html